# iPhone date picker, how to access individual items

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

Task: Show a UIDatePicker and grab the selected date, then display the selected date in a label (in the format of Day, Month, Year).

Current progress:

```
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *selected = [datePicker date];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", selected];

    date.text = message;
}
```

This will display the date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD 23:20:11 +0100. I do not want to display the time. I also want to display the date in a different format.

Is it possible to access the individual components of the date picker ie. datePicker.month

Any solutions or links is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:` method.  See [Apple's description of the method.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:)

For instance, to display the date in just the YYYY-MM-DD format, you'd use:

```
NSString *message = [selected descriptionWithCalendarFormat: @"%Y-%m-%d" timeZone: nil locale: nil]
```

I believe the format string here uses the same tokens as strptime from the C standard library, but there may be some minor discrepancies, knowing Apple.  A description of that format is [here.](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)

You could also use the NSDateFormatter class' [stringFromDate: method.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/stringFromDate:)  It uses a different format (the Unicode format).  I believe it is the "preferred" way to format date strings in Objective C, but it's probably a bit more complicated to use as well.

Finally, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583692/how-to-check-what-day-of-the-week-it-is-i-e-tues-fri-and-compare-two-nsdates) for information on extracting individual NSDate components.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much to all answers, used this line and got it all sorted.

Comment: Since you found this answer helpful, you can upvote it and/or mark it correct for the benefit of other users :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about accessing the individual components of the date picker, you can't. UIDatePicker doesn't inherit from UIPickerView, so they don't have API. However, the documentation does state that UIDatePicker "manages a custom picker-view object as a subview", which means you could traverse a UIDatePicker's subviews until you found a UIPickerView. Note that this is pretty risky, however.

Comment: What the OP wants is the components of the date, ie day, month, year.  You can get the date from the UIDatePicker using [UIDatePicker date] and then get individual components from that using NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *selected = [picker date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

//Set the required date format

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; //MM returns name of month small mm return the number.

//Get the string date

NSString* date = [formatter stringFromDate:selected];

//Display on the console

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is a special case uipickerview so you might be able to get the value in each component but I am not in front of Xcode to verify that.

You could however use NSDateFormatter to change the nsdateformatter returned to you into whatever format you are looking for.