# iPhone - how may I check if a date is Monday?

Tags: iphone, compare, nsdate, dayofweek, weekday

I'm trying to find if a date is Monday.

To do this I proceed this way :

```
#define kDateAndHourUnitsComponents NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// for test and debug purpose
NSDateComponents* b = [calendar components:kDateAndHourUnitsComponents fromDate:retDate];
int a=[[calendar components:kDateAndHourUnitsComponents fromDate:theDate] weekday];
// -----------

if ([[calendar components:kDateAndHourUnitsComponents fromDate:theDate] weekday] == EKMonday) DoThis....
```

But this doesn't work... a and b does not contain anything useful (a equals 2147483647),

I also wonder what can be the use of `[calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:retDate]` that is not useful anymore in that case...

I also found this that confirms the process :
[How to check what day of the week it is (i.e. Tues, Fri?) and compare two NSDates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583692/how-to-check-what-day-of-the-week-it-is-i-e-tues-fri-and-compare-two-nsdates)

What did I miss ?

Comment: It's always a good idea to have macro definitions in parenthesis.  Like this: `#define kDateAndHourUnitsComponents (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)`.  Otherwise it's very easy to introduce some very nasty hard to find problems.

Comment: OK, but these are always used this way without parenthesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go, this works and returns days via ints: 7 = Sat, 1 = Sun, 2 = Mon...

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
NSDate* curDate = [NSDate date];
int dayInt = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: curDate] weekday];
```

**SWIFT 4.2**

*Build up the date you want to check what day of the week it is*

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(
    year: 2019,
    month: 2 /*FEB*/,
    day: 23 /*23rd day of that month */
)
```

*get the current calendar.*

```
let cal = Calendar.current
```

*now use the calendar to check if the build up date is a valid date*

```
guard let date = cal.date(from: dateComponents ) else {
    // The date you build up wasn't a valid day on the calendar
    return
}

//Now that your date is validated, get the day of the week

let weekdayIndex = cal.component(.weekday, from: date)
```

*You'll notice that the 'weekdayIndex' is an integer. If you want to make it a string, you can do something like this:*

```
if let weekdayName = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols?[ weekdayIndex - 1] {
    print("The weekday for your date is :: \(weekdayName)")
}
```

*Instead of building your own date, you are of course allowed to use `let date = Date()` instead to get what the current day of the week is*

Comment: sorry but this just raises warnings at compile time and crashes the app at runtime, even deleting whitespaces after :

Comment: Sorry, I tried to remember that and screwed up my answer. Its fixed now, and I just put it in a project and verified it.

Comment: One thing I'm wondering: Is this dependent on the user's "Week Starts On" setting for the Calendar app?