# Switch "Day of the Week"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, case, switch-statement, dayofweek

I want to know the current day - and than do something special on this day

on monday = do this
on sunday = do that etc...

I know how to do the switch, but how can I ask to the current day?

```
if (...) { 
do something; 
} 
else { 
switch (..) {

case 0:
currentPageNumber = 2;
break;

case 1:
currentPageNumber = 3;

<...>
default:
break;
}
```

I think switch/case is the right way to do want I want. Thanks for helping me ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check what day of the week it is (i.e. Tues, Fri?) and compare two NSDates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583692/how-to-check-what-day-of-the-week-it-is-i-e-tues-fri-and-compare-two-nsdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSDate date]
```

Gives you the current date in your timezone

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]]
```

Gives you an `NSDateComponents` instance. You can get the weekday (value from 1-7/SU-SA) with

```
components.weekday
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code...

```
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:DateFrom];
```

This will give u an instance of NSDateComponents.you can get the weekday using..

```
int weekday1 = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

After that use ur logic..as

```
if (weekday1 == 1 ) 
   {
    //do something
   }
.
.
```

Note 1 means sunday and so on..