# Get week number and the date for monday and sunday in the current week (Objective-C on iOS)

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

how is it possible to get the current weeknumber and the date of monday and sunday in the current week?

Comment: To do this you read the specs for the components you've listed above.  And possibly do a little actual programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure how effeicient this is as it's mainly thrown together from, other answers

- [NSCalendar first day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106943/nscalendar-first-day-of-week)
- [How to check what day of the week it is (i.e. Tues, Fri?) and compare two NSDates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583692/how-to-check-what-day-of-the-week-it-is-i-e-tues-fri-and-compare-two-nsdate))

and  a quick skim of the apple docs for

- [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)
- [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents)
- [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
gregorian.firstWeekday = 2; // Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

NSUInteger weekOfYear = [components weekOfYear];

NSDate *mondaysDate = nil;
[gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&mondaysDate interval:NULL forDate:today];

NSLog(@"%ld %@", weekOfYear, mondaysDate);
```